# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifestForPackage'

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, gradle

im new to vscode and flutter. I want to try debug my flutter project in vscode. When i try to debugging, the debug console show this exception:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifestForPackage'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessPackagedManifestTask$WorkItem
   > Premature end of file.
```

I already did search for the answer and can't find any to solve that problem, any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello. I recommended you to add more info about your project.

Comment: @RoqueBarragan Previously i did flutter clean and pub get. Is that why i get the error?